Duplicate Check based on Hashes
I'm interested in esablishing a duplicate check for files within Sharepoint.
Sharepoint provides Hashes for Files as part of the driveItem-Facete
Example:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[DRIVEID]/items/[ITEMID]/children

delivers a Hash for Files:
{
        "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "[REMOVED]",
        "createdBy": {
            "user": {
                "email": "[REMOVED]",
                "id": "14cceb67-e4c3-4cd9-936b-e458b5ec02bc",
                "displayName": "[REMOVED]"
            }
        [REMOVED]
        
        "file": {
            "hashes": {
                "quickXorHash": "2zdtm06JkYgIcjP6RmvTsI6vvSw="
            },
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        },
        "size": 22335
    }

Im curiouss how to search for quickXorHash. Is there any possiblity?
